# Where does graphael (line chart) calculates it's maximum value?

Tags: javascript, charts, raphael, graphael

I am facing a very serious bug using graphael. Therefore, I want to change the procedure it uses to calculate the maximum value for the y axis. However, It's way to confusing for me, and I cannot find it. Can anyone help me to change that procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have any experience with gRaphael, but since no one else has answered, I might be able to help you somewhat...

The code for gRaphael's LineChart is [located here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21098797/1225950).

Normally, I would suggest overriding the function that calculates the y axis max value, but since that object is enclosed in a private scope, you will only be able to change the code, directly, through a local copy of that file.

I only skimmed the code, but was not able to find where in it the actual calculation was being done.

Answer (score 0):

It calculates them through the `.snapEnds()` method in gRaphael core. If you want, you can [expose the values to the linechart options using this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600158/change-min-and-max-y-axis-values-in-a-raphael-linechart/25583267#25583267).